# How to copy one sheet data to other sheet if cell conatin mention value?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have Sheet "Book List" which has all our books list with author name and price tag and stock. 
here is sheet

[image]

Now I want to arrange data by authors as I made more sheets based on author names, so I want to get all data from the main sheet to author wise on their sheets 
like all books name and price and stock for author 1 to Author 1 sheet 
here is a sheet of author names

[image: Author Name Sheet ( Author 1)]

I hope you got my points. hope I got help soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can use `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(BookList!A:D, BookList!B:B="Author 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I got my answer 
here is formula if anyone need

```
=query(BookList!A:D, "where B = 'Author 1' ",0)
```